# ERROR: in JAVA STAND ALONE: SEVERE: SAAJ0537: Invalid Content-Type. Could be an error message instead of a SOAP message

Tags: java, soap, webservice-client

Below is my JAVA stand alone class for SOAP Client. Am using keystore also. but am getting

> SEVERE: SAAJ0537: Invalid Content-Type. Could be an error message
>   instead of a SOAP message

Exception, tried hard, not able to figure it out. I have attached the los also below,

CODE:

```
public class SOAPClient {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        String keyStore = "XXXX/keystore_s1_ariba_uat.jks";

        System.getProperties().setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore",keyStore);
        System.getProperties().setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword","XXXX");
        System.getProperties().setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", keyStore);

        System.getProperties().setProperty("http.proxyHost", "web-proxy.XXXX.XXXX.net");
        System.getProperties().setProperty("https.proxyHost", "web-proxy.XXXX.XXXX.net");
        System.getProperties().setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8080");
        System.getProperties().setProperty("https.proxyPort", "8080");

        // Create SOAP Connection
        SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();

        // Send SOAP Message to SOAP Server
        String url = "https://s1.ariba.com/Sourcing/soap/hpegp-T/ContractHeaderExport?wsdl&validate=false";

        SOAPMessage soapMessage = createSOAPRequest();
        SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(soapMessage, url);

        // print SOAP Response
        System.out.print("Response SOAP Message:");
        soapResponse.writeTo(System.out);

        soapConnection.close();
    }


    private static SOAPMessage createSOAPRequest() throws Exception {
        MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
        //MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance(SOAPConstants.SOAP_1_1_PROTOCOL);

        SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
        SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();

        String serverURI = "urn:Ariba:Sourcing:vrealm_995";

        // SOAP Envelope
        SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
        envelope.setPrefix("soapenv");
        envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("urn", serverURI);

        // SOAP header        
        SOAPHeader soapHeader = envelope.getHeader();
        soapHeader.setPrefix("soapenv");

        SOAPElement soapHeaderElem = soapHeader.addChildElement("Headers", "urn");
        SOAPElement soapHeaderElemVarient = soapHeaderElem.addChildElement("variant", "urn");
        soapHeaderElemVarient.addTextNode("?");
        SOAPElement soapHeaderElemPartition = soapHeaderElem.addChildElement("partition", "urn");
        soapHeaderElemPartition.addTextNode("?");

        // SOAP Body
        SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();
        soapBody.setPrefix("soapenv");
        SOAPElement soapBodyElem = soapBody.addChildElement("ContractHeaderExportRequest", "urn");

        Name variantName = envelope.createName("variant");
        Name partitionName = envelope.createName("partition");
        soapBodyElem.addAttribute(variantName, "?");
        soapBodyElem.addAttribute(partitionName, "?");

        SOAPElement soapBodyElemWSContractHeader = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("WSContractHeaderExportInputBean_Item", "urn");
        SOAPElement soapBodyElemItem = soapBodyElemWSContractHeader.addChildElement("item", "urn");

        SOAPElement soapBodyElemClassName = soapBodyElemItem.addChildElement("ClassName", "urn");
        soapBodyElemClassName.addTextNode("ariba.collaborate.contracts.ContractWorkspace");

        SOAPElement soapBodyElemFromDate = soapBodyElemItem.addChildElement("FromDate", "urn");
        soapBodyElemFromDate.addTextNode("2015-01-01T12:00:00Z");

        SOAPElement soapBodyElemToDate = soapBodyElemItem.addChildElement("ToDate", "urn");
        soapBodyElemToDate.addTextNode("2016-04-29T12:00:00Z");

        //Mime Header
        MimeHeaders headers = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
        //headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", serverURI + "ContractHeaderExportRequest");
        headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", serverURI + "ContractHeaderExportRequest");
        headers.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
        //headers.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8");

        soapMessage.saveChanges();

        System.out.print("Request SOAP Message:");
        soapMessage.writeTo(System.out);

        return soapMessage;
    }

}
```

### LOGS:

> May 9, 2016 12:14:19 PM
>   com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl
>   identifyContentType SEVERE: SAAJ0537: Invalid Content-Type. Could be
>   an error message instead of a SOAP message Exception in thread "main"
>   com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl:
>   com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Invalid
>   Content-Type:text/html. Is this an error message instead of a SOAP
>   response?     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.call(HttpSOAPConnection.java:148)
>     at com.rnd.ws.soap.SOAPClient.main(SOAPClient.java:45) Caused by:
>   com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Invalid
>   Content-Type:text/html. Is this an error message instead of a SOAP
>   response?     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.identifyContentType(MessageImpl.java:602)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageFactoryImpl.createMessage(MessageFactoryImpl.java:86)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.post(HttpSOAPConnection.java:328)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.call(HttpSOAPConnection.java:144)
>     ... 1 more

CAUSE:

> com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Invalid
>   Content-Type:text/html. Is this an error message instead of a SOAP
>   response?     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.identifyContentType(MessageImpl.java:602)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageFactoryImpl.createMessage(MessageFactoryImpl.java:86)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.post(HttpSOAPConnection.java:328)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.call(HttpSOAPConnection.java:144)
>     at com.rnd.ws.soap.SOAPClient.main(SOAPClient.java:45)

Can any please help me in this?

Comment: Try to take a look at the message that was received. Like the exception says, it was probably an error page instead of a proper SOAP message.

Comment: Ya, but the html error page at lease how can be converted to view the error page?

Comment: Also check the server-side error log.